# How to loop through all columns in all tables in SQL server database and return column names juxtaposed with column values?

Tags: sql-server

I need to loop through all tables in my sql server database and for each table, I need to return values for all rows, but the tricky thing is I need the column name metadata returned side by side with the value for that column.

For example,

```
column1 collumn2 column3
A   B   C
AA  BB  CC
```

for this table, I need to return

```
column1     A   collumn2    B   column3 C
column1     AA  collumn2    BB  column3
```

CC

I have script using cursor to loop through all tables and within each table, return all columns' name (but not value).

I also have script returning the column names and values one by one, as

```
column1 A
column1 AA
column2 B
column2 BB
column3 C
column3 CC
```

But I need to return one row of column metadat + column vaue for each row of data. Does anyone have any insight? I am still poking around. Thanks!

Edited:
I finally got the script working

```
drop table #results
CREATE TABLE #Results (TypeColumnName nvarchar(100), TypeColumnValue int, CodeValueName nvarchar(100), CodeValueValue nvarchar(100), DescriptionName nvarchar(100), DescriptionValue nvarchar(1024) )

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @sql nvarchar(max), @sql0 nvarchar(max)
    SET  @TableName = ''


    WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN

        SET @ColumnName = ''
        set @sql=''
        SET @TableName = 
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            and table_schema = 'test'
            and table_name like 'sales%'
                AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
        )

        WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN

            SET @ColumnName =
            (
                SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                    AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                    AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
            )
            IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                --select @columnname
                set @sql = @sql + '''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''',' + @ColumnName + ', '

            END
            ELSE
            begin
            SET @sql = left(rtrim(@sql),Len(rtrim(@sql))-1) 
            set @sql = 'SELECT ' + @sql +   ' FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' 

    select @sql 
    INSERT INTO #Results
                EXEC sp_executesql @sql 
    end


END

end
```

Comment: What language are you programming in? Where do you want your output to go? To a file? To the screen?

Comment: Perhaps if you say what you are doing with the data, we can advise better.

Comment: T-SQL. I want the output to go to a global temporary table. Thank you!

Comment: @cometbill, I am needing this output as I will be looping through this output and construct CASE WHEN statements using column names and values. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Does this get you started ?

```
select t.name, c.name, c.system_type_id , c.max_length 
         ,Case c.system_type_id
         when 167 then 'VarChar'
         When 231 then 'nVarChar'
         when 4 then 'Integer'
         when 56 then 'int'
         when 61 then 'DateTime'
         else 'Unknown'
         End 
   from sys.tables t
 inner join sys.columns c
    on c.object_id = t.object_id 
 order by t.name, c.column_ID
```

This T-SQL that I knocked together works in SQL Server 2008 R2

You can use sp_help to figure out other 'unknown' column types and add them in the case statement yourself.

Comment: Thanks much @cometbill - this unfortunately only gives me metadata while I need to look at the actual values of the column in addition to the column name so I can construct case statement. This is mainly for lookup tables, which for example has code and description columns so I can build case statement as                   case when [code column name] = 'code value' then [description column name] = 'description value'

Comment: @Wendy you want the metadata AND the data?  you can determine the field type once you have the field with some data in it. I'm not sure why you want to wset the description value only if the code value was a certain code. I'm confuzzled.

Answer (score 0):

Use the UNPIVOT functionality:

`SELECT col1, colval
FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, col3
    FROM table1
) UNPIVOT (
    colval for colname IN (col2, col3)
) as unpiv`

You can add joins and where clauses in different spots to filter however you need. In one of my applications I filtered and joined in the first query, then joined the end result to a couple more tables, etc...

You can also do the reverse with PIVOT functionality in a very similar manner. Check out the Books Online for these two functions... I think they'll solve your issue for you.

Comment: John, I forgot UNPIVOT function - I just experimented with it a little and it still doesn't work to solve my case as I need also to pull in column names. But it's good to have that handy. Thanks much!

Comment: When I run it, I get column names and corresponding values. So basically it takes my wide table, and makes it into a tall table. I think if you keep trying it will do what you need.